# Spacemacs - opening and creating files

Tags: files, spacemacs

Lets say I'm already in emacs and I need to open some obscure file (long complicated path) that I rarely ever edit (so its not in my recent files list) - what is the correct way to do this using spacemacs shortcuts?

Currently I have to use helm and manually type the path to the file. Id rather have some sort of browser where I could look at directory structures and select folders to "cd" into

Secondly, lets say I need to create a brand new file in some obscure directory. Again, what is the correct spacemacs way to create this new file?

I'm pretty new to emacs so the way that I'm currently doing this things (manually typing paths in helm) feels very slow and I'm mostly wondering whether this is common or whether theres another way to do these things that I'm not aware of

Comment: I voted to close this question because I think it's too broad in its current form. What is "quick" for you? As few keystrokes as possible? As fast as possible?  As easy as possible so that you don't need to pause and think?

Comment: Spacemacs has a layer implementing fasd: https://github.com/steckerhalter/emacs-fasd see https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Btools/fasd

Comment: Also, what's "obscure" in this case? Is it a file that you visit only infrequently or rarely?  Or does the file have a complicated path?  Or does it even move between different locations (e.g. like a temporary directory)?

Comment: honestly, I'm so new to spacemacs that I dont even know how to open or create files that are not in projects. So really I'm just looking for the typical way that people do this. I'll edit the question to reflect this

Comment: @Simon: It would be best if you took a look at some tutorials on Emacs (or try the built-in one with `C-h t`) if you're having trouble with something as basic as creating/opening files.

Comment: Hm, I think this question is clear, at least the last part and offers chance for a clear answer. 
Which I am looking for myself btw. It's a pity everything that seems obviously to advanced users is closed for some obscure reason.
Also if every answer to a question would be RTFM,  what is the purpose of SO then?

Comment: One possible way to create a brand new file is ```SPC b b``` (i.e. ```helm-mini``` under buffers) and start typing away a name for a buffer. If it is not matching any open buffer, a new one is created (after ```RET```). Saving this buffer happens with ```SPC f s```, and you can go to any location you want through ```TAB```.

Comment: You get a browser for your files by toggeling NeoTree, ```SPC f t```.